# How to pass json string from jsp page to Spring mvc controller?

Tags: java, json, ajax, string, spring-mvc

I need to pass a json string from my jsp page to spring mvc controller.My JSON String and its passing using ajax call is shown below

```
var datejson = '{'
           +'"startmonth" : smonth,'
           +'"startday"  : sday,'
           +'"endmonth" : emonth,'
           +'"endday" : eday'
           +'}';    
    alert("json created");
    //var jsonfile={json:JSON.stringify(datejson)};
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "/pms/season/json/",
        data: JSON.stringify(datejson),
        success: function(data) { 
            alert(data.startmonth + " " + data.endmonth);
        },
        error:function(data,status,er) { 
            alert("error: "+data+" status: "+status+" er:"+er);
        }
    });
```

Every time my error function alerts.So how to pass it?
The code to recieve json in Controller class is shown below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void validationDate( @RequestParam ("json") String datejson)
    {
        //System.out.println("JSON TEST");
        System.out.println("JSON CONTENTS ARE::::::"+ datejson );
    }
```

I am new to jquery.Any help will be highly appreciable...

Comment: What is the error message?  Can you add a breakpoint on the server side to see what is being passed in to `validationDate()` ?

Comment: error message is" error: [object Object] status: error er:Not Found".The serverside wont gets called.The error message is at sending ajax request.

Comment: Is your Tomcat and application up and running?  I would expect that the server would be getting hit assuming your AJAX call be set up correctly with a valid URL.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yeah my server is working correctly and my application is running,expect this block.Is anything wrong inside my controller code?

Comment: You just said the server is not being hit.  If this be the case, then you should be checking your UI code.